# Drool with Wildfly is not responding under Load

Tags: wildfly, drools, rule-engine

I have set up Drool rule Engine 7.15 with Wildfly 15.0(jboss) server version. Normally it works fine. But when the Load is more to the rule Engine i.e more request concurrently come. It stops responding until the rule is deployed again.
This could be the issue with the container of wildfly. Can any one help inthis regard.

-ram

Comment: Any one can help on this

Comment: If you could provide a reproducer / unit test it would appreciated. There is not sufficient amount of information in your initial posts to be able to move forward with this issue.

Comment: Dear Anton Giertli,

Comment: Dear Anton Giertli,   I am using 'wildfly-17.0.0.Final' server and deployed 'kie-server-7.17.0.0.war' along with this my application code as 'kie-builder.war' also deployed. Now I have deployed 10 rules also.  Everything works fine when I hit few requests to the server 'http://localhost:8080/kie-server/services/rest/server/containers/instances/RRTRULE'  with a valid jSON. It returns the expected result as which rule applied. But when I hit the same URL aprox 20 times in quick succession the rule engine stops responding till I restart the server. And It gives below logs as in the Answer section

Answer (score 0):

Dear Anton Giertli,

I am using 'wildfly-17.0.0.Final' server and deployed 'kie-server-7.17.0.0.war' along with this my application code as 'kie-builder.war' also deployed. Now I have deployed 10 rules also.  Everything works fine when I hit few requests to the server 'http://localhost:8080/kie-server/services/rest/server/containers/instances/RRTRULE'  with a valid jSON. It returns the expected result as which rule applied.

But

- when I hit the same URL **aprox 20** times in quick succession

  the rule engine stops responding till I restart the server or deploy rules again. Is there any configuration that prevents this API call beyond 20 times.

It gives below logs:-

12:09:33,446 INFO  [org.apache.activemq.audit.base] (Thread-15 (ActiveMQ-remoting-threads-ActiveMQServerImpl::serverUUID=f5b54bf7-da0d-11e9-8113-c8d3ffe781b3-1841659077)) AMQ601267: User anonymous is creating a core session on target resource ActiveMQServerImpl::serverUUID=f5b54bf7-da0d-11e9-8113-c8d3ffe781b3 [with parameters: [3d9b4ea8-daa8-11e9-9773-c8d3ffe781b3, d172f474-d677-475b-9a19-d86f11660118, ****, 102400, RemotingConnectionImpl [ID=3d99ef16-daa8-11e9-9773-c8d3ffe781b3, clientID=null, nodeID=f5b54bf7-da0d-11e9-8113-c8d3ffe781b3, transportConnection=InVMConnection [serverID=0, id=3d99ef16-daa8-11e9-9773-c8d3ffe781b3]], false, false, false, true, null, org.apache.activemq.artemis.core.protocol.core.impl.CoreSessionCallback@6385727e, true, OperationContextImpl [646439018] [minimalStore=9223372036854775807, storeLineUp=0, stored=0, minimalReplicated=9223372036854775807, replicationLineUp=0, replicated=0, paged=0, minimalPage=9223372036854775807, pageLineUp=0, errorCode=-1, errorMessage=null, executorsPending=0, executor=OrderedExecutor(tasks=[])], {}]]
12:09:59,267 INFO  [stdout] (default task-1) rule_MP_Refund and Then Pick up   97
12:10:00,936 INFO  [stdout] (default task-1) rule_MP_Refund and Then Pick up   97
12:10:01,925 INFO  [stdout] (default task-1) rule_MP_Refund and Then Pick up   97
12:10:02,906 INFO  [stdout] (default task-1) rule_MP_Refund and Then Pick up   97
12:10:03,854 INFO  [stdout] (default task-1) rule_MP_Refund and Then Pick up   97
12:10:04,733 INFO  [stdout] (default task-1) rule_MP_Refund and Then Pick up   97
12:10:05,905 INFO  [stdout] (default task-1) rule_MP_Refund and Then Pick up   97
12:10:06,905 INFO  [stdout] (default task-1) rule_MP_Refund and Then Pick up   97
12:10:08,025 INFO  [stdout] (default task-1) rule_MP_Refund and Then Pick up   97
12:10:09,007 INFO  [stdout] (default task-1) rule_MP_Refund and Then Pick up   97
12:10:10,221 INFO  [stdout] (default task-1) rule_MP_Refund and Then Pick up   97
12:10:11,231 INFO  [stdout] (default task-1) rule_MP_Refund and Then Pick up   97
12:10:12,155 INFO  [stdout] (default task-1) rule_MP_Refund and Then Pick up   97
12:10:13,208 INFO  [stdout] (default task-1) rule_MP_Refund and Then Pick up   97
12:10:14,151 INFO  [stdout] (default task-1) rule_MP_Refund and Then Pick up   97
12:10:15,101 INFO  [stdout] (default task-1) rule_MP_Refund and Then Pick up   97
12:10:16,191 INFO  [stdout] (default task-1) rule_MP_Refund and Then Pick up   97
12:10:17,173 INFO  [stdout] (default task-1) rule_MP_Refund and Then Pick up   97
12:10:18,103 INFO  [stdout] (default task-1) rule_MP_Refund and Then Pick up   97
12:10:18,142 WARN  [org.drools.core.rule.constraint.MvelConstraint] (drools-worker-2) Exception jitting: $rm.getReturnScore() >= (0.0) || 0 == 0.0 This is NOT an error and NOT prevent the correct execution since the constraint will be evaluated in intrepreted mode
12:10:18,143 WARN  [org.drools.core.rule.constraint.MvelConstraint] (drools-worker-1) Exception jitting: $rm.getReturnScore() <= (0.0) || 0 == 0.0 This is NOT an error and NOT prevent the correct execution since the constraint will be evaluated in intrepreted mode
12:10:18,143 WARN  [org.drools.core.rule.constraint.MvelConstraint] (drools-worker-3) Exception jitting: $rm.getDiscount() <= (0.0) || 0 == 0.0 This is NOT an error and NOT prevent the correct execution since the constraint will be evaluated in intrepreted mode
12:10:18,143 WARN  [org.drools.core.rule.constraint.MvelConstraint] (drools-worker-4) Exception jitting: $rm.getDiscount() >= (0.0) || 0 == 0.0 This is NOT an error and NOT prevent the correct execution since the constraint will be evaluated in intrepreted mode
12:10:18,155 WARN  [org.drools.core.rule.constraint.MvelConstraint] (drools-worker-1) Exception jitting: $rm.getPrice() <= (0.0) || 0 == 0.0 This is NOT an error and NOT prevent the correct execution since the constraint will be evaluated in intrepreted mode
12:10:18,155 WARN  [org.drools.core.rule.constraint.MvelConstraint] (drools-worker-3) Exception jitting: $rm.getPrice() >= (0.0) || 0 == 0.0 This is NOT an error and NOT prevent the correct execution since the constraint will be evaluated in intrepreted mode
12:10:18,151 WARN  [org.drools.core.rule.constraint.MvelConstraint] (drools-worker-2) Exception jitting: $rm.getPrice() >= (10000.0) || 0 == 10000.0 This is NOT an error and NOT prevent the correct execution since the constraint will be evaluated in intrepreted mode

Answer (score 0):

!! This issues is resolved (Followed: [Disable JIT in Drools 6.2 with Java 8](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33074146/disable-jit-in-drools-6-2-with-java-8) )

1) After adding the jvm property(-Ddrools.jittingThreshold=-1) to stop JIT Compiler during rule Execution. 
2) Moreover, we see that '.contains()' was creating the issue and changing it to ' contains ' also solves this issue inside .drt file.

((("@{pincode}").split(",")).contains($rm.getPincode()) || "*".equals("@{pincode}")),
                 changed to :-
((("@{pincode}").split(",")) contains ($rm.getPincode()) || "*".equals("@{pincode}")),